# Strace with redirection

Tags: strace

How can I use strace to include output redirection (>), for example:

```
strace echo Hello > /tmp/file
```

The output produced is only taking into account `echo hello` but not `> /tmp/file`

I have also tried:

```
alice@vm:~$ strace -e trace=open,close,read,write echo Hello > /tmp/file

close(3)                                = 0
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
close(3)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(1, "Hello\n", 6)                  = 6
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

It shows that it is writing to stdout (file descriptor 1), but no where shows that it is redirecting to /tmp/file.

Answer (score 4):

## Stracing command with redirection

`strace sh -c "echo Hello > /tmp/foo"`

---

## Redirecting strace's output to the output stream

From [strace man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

> The name of each system call, its arguments and its return value are printed on standard error or to the file specified with the -o option.

So, that's how we can redirect the standard error to some file:

`strace echo Hello 2>/tmp/file`

Another option is to use the `-o` flag:

`strace -o"/tmp/file2" echo hello`

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, my question is concerning the redirection of the echo command to /tmp/file, not the strace output itself. i.e. I want to see the systemcalls that are involved in redirecting stdout to a file.

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited my answer with appropriate solution. Is this answer solves the problem? :)

Comment: "-o" solved my problem